# Double event handler and one function. How to prevent executing code twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, jquery-events

I have one callback function bound to two events (`change` and `focusout`). However, I need the `focusout` to happen only when the element we're interacting with is not a `checkbox`.

This is the example code:

```
$(document).on('focusout change', '.selector', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checkbox')) {
        // Do stuff and prevent the focusout to trigger. HOW???
    }

    doStuff(); // Action that applies to both cases, but needs to be limited at one execution only
});
```

The code above will execute twice:

- When the checkbox gets checked/unchecked
- When you click outside of the checkbox (lose focus (blur))

I tried using `.off`, but it ends up killing the `focousout` handler altogether, which I will need later for other elements which aren't checkboxes.

What would be the way to prevent the `focusout` handler to trigger for certain elements?

Comment: don't add event listener to elements you don't want to listen on those events - judicious use of classes will help

Comment: Well I need the `focusout` on a million different things and I need to avoid code repetition as well.

Comment: well, add a class to those you don't want, and look for it and the event name (it'll be focusout or change) in your code - your code isn't clear enough to give an example unfortunately - but here's a hint. the event handler receives as it's first argument the event that triggered the handler, this argument has a property called name, which is the name of the event (focusout/change) - given this and the logic you must already possess to identify the elements you don't want a focusout event to execute your code, you should be able to avoid the code quite easily

Comment: @JaromandaX You can post your `event.type` suggestion as an answer and I'll accept it. I fixed the issue by using it.

Comment: oh, it's `type` not `name` ... see, taught you to fish instead of giving you a fish :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is

```
$(document).on('focusout change', '.selector', function(event) {
```

`event` is an event object, which has properties, one of which is `type`. Checking the `type` you can now see if your function has been called because of a `focusout` or a `change` and run code as appropriate

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to affect **both events** (or more) to the **same function**, like this :

A text input for example

```
<input id="myfield" type="text" />
```

Now the Javascript

```
var myfield = document.getElementById('myfield');

myfield.onfocus = myfield.onchange = function(e)
{
    //your code
}
```

Yo can even add an other element

```
button.onclick = myfield.onkeyup = function(e)
{
    //when the client press the enter key
    if(e.key && e.key == "Enter")
    {
        //catch the target
    }
    //when the client click the button
    else if(!e.key || e.target == button)
    {
        //catch the target
    }

    //otherwise you can do not care about the target and just execute your function
}
```

You must only know that you can add many elements and many events

```
element1.onfocus = element1.onblur = element2.onchange = element3.onchange = function(e){//your code}
```